# Span within a headline doesn't wrap correctly when using react-text-loop

Tags: reactjs

Currently trying to create a headline containing a span in my React app. The span's content loops using TextLoop, imported from react-text-loop. All works well until I try to view it on a smaller device, at which point the content inside the span overflows off the page if it's too long, instead of wrapping as I'd expect it to.

[Here's a code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-lichterman-si5cr?file=/src/App.js) with the relevant code. It has three examples — the text as a plain headline (exactly what I'm after), the headline containing a span (not quite what I want but would settle for it), and the headline containing spans wrapped in a TextLoop (overflows). Any help is appreciated!